# Group By for Core Data Results

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, group-by

I am using Core Data and generally, I have a Game, a Game Phase, and points scored for different types of actions *(lets say pointsA, pointsB)*.

Each game consists of two phases and there are hence for each player a total points per phase and then per game *(phase 1 + phase 2)*.

My **Score** Entity in Core Data has:

1. **Player** (Relationship to player),
2. **Game** (Relationship to game),
3. **Phase** (attribute),
4. **PointsA** (attribute),
5. **PointsB** (attribute).

So each player has a record for a Score in a Phase in a Game.

In order to get in fetch all points for a given player *AGGREGATED BY GAME* (so SQL equivalent of "Group By"). I managed to use this code and *IT WORKS*:

**CODE:**

```
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Score" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"player == %@",_currentPlayer];

NSExpressionDescription* ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.pointsA"]];
[ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
[ex setName:@"pointsA"];

NSExpressionDescription* ex2 = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex2 setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.pointsB"]];
[ex2 setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
[ex2 setName:@"pointsB"];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Game",ex, ex2,nil]];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Game",nil]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];

results= [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

My question is: Suppose I have *MANY MORE POINTS TYPES*, as in **pointsC**, **PointsD**, etc.. (let's say scores for many more different kinds of actions). Do I have to use a *SEPARATE*  `NSExpressionDescription` (ex and ex2 above) for all of these ?

Is this really how long winded it is in Core Data? Is there a quicker way?

I am relatively new to Core Data.

For those who are wondering how to parse through the results set:

```
for (id Res  in results) {

    NSLog(@"pointsA: %@   ", Res[@"pointsA"] );
    NSLog(@"pointsB: %@   ", [Res valueForKey:@"pointsB"] );
    //both work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, answering my own question: I guess a more elegant way would be to feed in an array of items with the Core Data attribute names, which can then be as long as you want:

(NSArray*)items contains pointsA, pointsB, pointsC, pointsD, all the way to z and beyond if you so require.

///Code///

```
-(void)fetchRes:(NSArray*)items
{
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Score" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"player == %@",_currentPlayer];

    NSMutableArray *propsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Game", nil];

    for (int i=0;i<items.count;i++)

    {
      NSString *desc=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"@sum.%@",items[i]];

        NSExpressionDescription* ex3 = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        [ex3 setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:desc]];
        [ex3 setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
        [ex3 setName:items[i]];

       [propsArray insertObject:ex3 atIndex:i+1];
     }

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:propsArray];

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Game",nil]];
   [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];

    results=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] ;

}
```

Not sure what the performance / memory consequences are ?